# Follow-up: Using an old P4 as a web server

Tags: discussion

It's really stupid that questions like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/388738/using-an-old-p4-as-a-web-server) get closed without further explanation. It's even more stupid when they are flagged as off-topic when it's talking about servers, LAMPs and the like. Isn't that talking about servers? Or is this a site about footbal and I came here by mistake?

> Questions on Server Fault are expected to generally relate to servers, networking, or desktop infrastructure, within the scope defined in the faq.

It's not because it was my question. It's because it's not off-topic at all. However, if your attitude it to close a topic without explaning why it is not a good fit for your "world-class" (?!) Q&A format I don't need this site at all. Now I conclude that coming here is purely a waste of time. I don't need rude people.

PS-Go straight ahead and ban me right away for these words. I wouldn't come here anymore either, so I really don't care...

Comment: The [FAQ] also states that questions regarding your home network are off-topic, even if they are about your home *server*. Furthermore, it states that questions are to be asked about these topics in a professional capacity. A personal home server is something else by definition.

Comment: For what it's worth, we don't ban people for being upset, or disagreeing with people (with one notable exception). We're all professionals here with professional day jobs; we have better things to do with our time than get into fights on the internet. So feel free to ragequit as much as you like, but you *are* welcome back.

Answer (score 14):

First line of the FAQ:

> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

Your question doesn't fit before we even get to what it is, because you're not acting in a professional capacity.

My apologies, we have a different audience than most of the Stack Exchange sites, so I can understand your confusion. You are not the first. But the site begged you to read the FAQ before posting your Question, which you did not.